# CASE statement IF ELSE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this `select` statement and what I am trying to accomplish is to get data in the
`DosagePerUnits` column only if `Dosage` is not equal to empty or 1 and if `Units` is not empty or 1.

Can someone help me please ?

```
select 
    sbd.Code, c.Description, sbd.Dosage, 
    Case 
        when sbd.Units = '' then '1' 
        else sbd.Units 
    end as Units, 
    ad.ApptDate, sbd.RCycle, sbd.RWeek, sbd.RDay, 
    t.HistoryOrder, t.TypeId, sbd.Dosage + '/' + sbd.UnitsAS DosagePerUnits
from
    bill_SuperBillDetail sbd, 
    bill_ProcedureVerification pv, 
    AppointmentData ad,
    CPTCode c, 
    CPTType t
where 
    sbd.AccessionNumber = pv.AccessionNumber
    and pv.ApptId = ad.ApptId
    and ad.PatientId = 443
    and ad.ApptDate <= GETDATE()
    and ad.ApptDate > '2009-11-15 00:00:00.000'
    and c.TypeId = t.TypeId
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it should be like this:

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(sbd.Dosage, '1') <> '1' AND ISNULL(sbd.Units, '1') <> '1' THEN
sbd.Dosage + '/' + sbd.Units
ELSE NULL END AS DosagePerUnits
```

`ISNULL(x, 1)` replaces x with 1 if it is null. So `ISNULL(x, 1)`  is = 1 if x is either 1 or NULL.

EDIT:
Changed to the assumption that [Dosage] and [Unit] are both *varchar* as your comment indicates.

Comment: when i try to implement i get the following:  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '235.67' to data type int.

Comment: I have edited my answer... Although I'm not sure if floating point numbers stored as strings are such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
 Case when sbd.Units = '' then '1' else sbd.Units end as Units, 
try 
Coalesce(sbd.Units,1) as Units,

Answer (score 0):

If any part of the calculation is null the whole thing will be null. You can use this fact this way:

```
nullif(nullif(sbd.Dosage, ''), '1') + '/' + nullif(nullif(sbd.Units, ''), '1') AS DosagePerUnits
```

This will result in DosagePerUnits being null when one of the columns are '', '1' or null

I thought i had a really clever answer here. Oh well, I guess it wasn't that clever. Does anyone know why I am unable to write comments ?